# Handling pseudo-elements ::before and ::after when targeting IE6 IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, pseudo-element

Can any CSS3 experts tell me the best strategy for handling the before and after pseudo elements with IE6 and IE7?

Comment: I think this [link](http://nanobox.chipx86.com/blog/2006/07/before-and-after-in-ie7-and-below.php) can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use jQuery it is a simple one-liner. Just use prepend() and inject a span with a class .before (for the simplicity of changing the CSS). I've made [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Flocke/QjT8p/) for you.

Answer (score 0):

I write a small script for old IE to add special elements in DOM. (Via IE conditional comments.) The rest of common browsers get this by pure CSS. The downside is I have to write the code twice. The upside, I have IE only code in one place.