# make css menu that works on IE6 and 7

Tags: html, css

I am assigned a task and will create a pure css menu that works on all browsers including IE6 and 7. I have to use :hover pseudo class. As these classes are not supported in IE6 still is there are workaround for this using css? If yes please how to do it?

Comment: You can achieve this in JavaScript. What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can do it with JS, but you should also consider that less than 1% of internet users still uses these two browsers.

Comment: Take a look at whatever:hover http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/csshover.html

Comment: Don't. Pure CSS menus are horrible at the best of times (they are *very* hard to make accessible) and IE 6 is awful at CSS.

Comment: `:hover` is supported on IE6, however only on anchor tags. Also why on Earth are you still supporting IE6? If you're not targeting China, you're looking at 0.3% of your user base.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of tools available on the web for IE6 ~ IE7 pesky fallback.
Check this out:

http://selectivizr.com/

Or if you just want something smaller, look here:

[IE6 ~ IE7 great css3 pseudo elements fallback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8457828/handling-pseudo-elements-before-and-after-when-targeting-ie6-ie7)

Good luck,
George!